# Pandas aggregate multiindex and then pivot

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, pivot-table

I have a pandas dataframe

```
> df
             Close                                         ...       Dividends               
                   WHR        WLTW        WMB        WYNN  ...       ZBH ZBRA ZION  ZTS
Date                                                       ...                         
2018-12-31   98.651924  146.821838  18.532253   94.978737  ...       0.0    0  0.0  0.0
2019-01-02   99.621178  144.714127  18.843227  100.250526  ...       0.0    0  0.0  0.0
2019-01-03   99.288864  141.678299  19.002914   99.280663  ...       0.0    0  0.0  0.0
```

I would like to take an average over time axis

```
> df.mean(axis=0)
Close      WHR     132.339759
           WLTW    179.843761
           WMB      22.007237
           WYNN    120.427202
           XEL      56.132715
           XLNX    105.113807
           XYL      75.654389
           YUM     100.469046
           ZBH     127.807681
           ZBRA    209.234944
           ZION     43.799284
           ZTS     110.658934
Dividends  WHR       0.017658
           WLTW      0.009665
           WMB       0.005651
           WYNN      0.013941
           XEL       0.006022
           XLNX      0.005465
           XYL       0.003569
           YUM       0.006245
           ZBH       0.003569
           ZBRA      0.000000
           ZION      0.004758
           ZTS       0.003182
```

But how can I now pivot this table to look like

```
          Dividends    Close
WHR       0.017658     132.339759
WLTW      0.009665     179.843761
WMB       0.005651      22.007237
WYNN      0.013941     120.427202
XEL       0.006022      56.132715
XLNX      0.005465     105.113807
XYL       0.003569      75.654389
YUM       0.006245     100.469046
ZBH       0.003569     127.807681
ZBRA      0.000000     209.234944
ZION      0.004758      43.799284
ZTS       0.003182     110.658934
```

I have multiindex columns and a time series index in the original table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) per first level:

```
df.mean(axis=0).unstack(level=0)
```